# Need help plotting a ggplot of percentage of categories in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency

I have a data frame, that has some number of columns. Each of these columns has values that are categorical - Yes, Neutral and No. An example of the dataframe is below:

```
a = c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'neutral', 'no', 'yes','no','neutral','neutral')
b = c('no', 'yes','no', 'no', 'no', 'neutral', 'yes', 'neutral','neutral')
abcd = data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to plot a ggplot - a Grouped (edited from stacked) bar plot that says for a - the number of yes, no and neutral and similarly for b. There are a lot of columns, so geom_bar() for each column is not feasible

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
abcd %>% 
  gather(key = "letter", value = "Response") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(letter, fill = Response)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of columns. is there a way I can do it not manually?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make it long format using pivot_longer (or gather or melt, whichever you prefer), and then

```
library(dplyr)
# everything means all columns, like your case
abcd %>% 
pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=name,fill=value))
```

[image]